# String simulation with R

Tags: r, simulation

I am new with R.
I would like to know how to simulate string data for example

```
> ABCDAABCDRFSSAAABE 

> ABCDDEDEEEF

> AABBCCDDDDEABCEDFABD 

> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `base R` functions to randomize both the letters chosen and the number of samples. You can choose how many vectors for output. The vector `LETTERS` is an in-built vector of uppercase alpha characters. :

```
replicate(3, sample(LETTERS, size=sample(length(LETTERS))))
```

Comment: A little explanation might be nice regarding what `letters` and `LETTERS` do in R.

Comment: From what I understand from the OP's post, he/she needs a single string.  Anyway, another unfair voting.

Comment: I believe OP is looking multiple vectors. Which is why they mentioned to you that your first solution only produced one. Secondly, people are free to vote as they please. You are not the final judge on the merits of answers.

Comment: Yes, the OP mentioned that and I corrected it.  But, it is still a string instead of a vector from the OP's post.  Anyway, unfair voting is unfair voting.  No question about that.  I am not the final judge, but you can do some benchmarks, which would at least give some merit.

Comment: Also, please remove your nasty comments from my other post, alright.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `stri_rand_strings` from `library(stringi)`

```
library(stringi)
stri_rand_strings(1, 8, '[A-Z]')
#[1] "PZFBVYVJ"
```

If we need multiple strings with different number of letters, just change the `n` and `length`

```
stri_rand_strings(2, sample(8:16, 2, replace=FALSE),'[A-Z]')
#[1] "XABWTQRDKCPSHKY" "SWPIARRENKCHHO"
```

According to the documentation the usage is

> stri_rand_strings(n, length, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]")

One advantage for using the `stringi` function is the speed.  It would be very fast.  Another thing with respect to the other solution is that this is not looping.  `replicate` is using `sapply` which is a loop.